# Difficult MYSQL-Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following database:

[image]

And I want to count all the entries with the same `teamname`, so that I know how many players are in one team. Then i want to check if the teamsize is all ready the size of the NumbersOfMembers and if not so show me them.

The idea is, that I can see which team is not fully completed.

Comment: `SELECT` - `COUNT()` - `WHERE` clause, conditional statements, echo etc.. You can look all of those up to get you started.The question is far too broad and hold too many possible answers. Go through tutorials/manuals, then come back when you have a problem with code; we'll be glad to help then.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed and tested version of [Dans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677677/3595565):

```
SELECT teamname, count(*) AS TeamSize, max(numberOfMembers) AS maxMembers 
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY teamname 
HAVING TeamSize < maxMembers
```

But you should normalize your table. No need to repeat the general teamdata and restrictions for every user.

Comment: Wow Guys i did not expect such a fast and good answers yes it is exactly what i was looking for thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Would Something like this work?

```
SELECT teamname, count(*) as TeamSize group by teamname having count(*) < numberOfMembers
```

This is just a theoretical answer, untested.

Comment: To use numberOfMembers into the having clause, you need to take it into the group by or select + missing the from